# Crystal Reports Suppress multiple fields with one condition

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to suppress multiple fields in a detail line based on the same condition. Can I somehow link these fields together so I have One Suppress Condition for all of them at once, as oppose to create the same  condition for each field  ?
Thank you for your help in advance 
Magdalena

Comment: Unless you want to suppress the entire Details Section, you'll have to add the condition to each field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple "subsections" in details section and suppress one or more "subsections".

Comment: Isnt that still adding multiple conditions. The question is to add the condition ONLY once.

Comment: You will set the condition on the "subsection" level and will hide multiple fields by hiding the section

Answer (score 0):

May be you can create a subreport on the Details section with the fields you want dynamically hidden, and then add the condition only once on the subreport. That hides all the fields at once.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions.

I found what I was looking for.

Here is my solution, step by step:

1.)Drop all the interested fields in the Detail Section

2.)Insert a Text Object in the Detail Section and drag the fields to be grouped (for formatting/suppressing purposes) into the Text Object

3.)Suppress the Text Object with the desired condition; all the fields that were included in the test object will be suppressed when condition is true.

(I had a screenshot as well, but can't post it since I don't have enough reputation- sorry)